# FOX FLOAT CTD Evolution oil leak :(

Tags: mountain-bike, maintenance, full-suspension, shocks, sealant

I have a FOX FLOAT CTD Evolution LV 184x44mm, which worked fine in the summer, afther the cold weather arrived, and I started to ride under 15C, it started to leak some oil. It was pretty nasty, but I wasn't able to do anything, my bike is stored in non heated garrage, so it can get pretty chilly out there, -5C.

Now the temperature started to rise, so I bought a service kit, with seals, and a friend of mine, came by to replace them, like [on this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yaT2k3lq600)

But even after this, the oil leaks like there is something broken. The shock still works fine, it has 3 modes, and the lock still converts it to a hardtail, and the folly open, gives a nice bouncy feel to the ride.

[image] it looks like this after 15km 10 tarmac / 5 offroad

Does anyone has an idea what can cause this problem? I did not crashed withe the bike, once, and in the summer there was not a single drop of oil on the stanchion, even after 2500km of offroad. :((

[image]
This is how it looks after 30km :(

Hope you can help me. (Please do not suggest to got to the local bike shops, they don't work with fox shocks)

Comment: That looks like the blue Float fluid in the air can is migrating through the wiper seal. I clean my Fox a couple of times a year and immediately after the service I do get a small amount of grease leakage on the shaft. I would keep an eye on it and observe if the amount slows down over the next few rides. TLDR don’t panic yet.

Answer (score 2):

I am certainly no expert in shocks, only ever stripped one model a couple of times...

Is the shock holding pressure?  If so, its the wiper seals leaking not the aircan seal - check the damper body for scratches/damage. If not external damage I would re-service the shock pay special attention to the damper body condition and that the damper seals were correctly reassembled.

If the shock is loosing pressure, it will be the aircan seals. Check the internal surface of the aircan for scratches.